# generating bar chart with angular and nvd3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nvd3.js

I am trying to generate a bar chart using angularJS and nvD3. My controller is like this:

```
function initMyController(fac, $scope, DATA_URL, $http){
    $http.get(DATA_URL).success(function(response){
      console.log(response);
      var values = [];
      $scope.data = [];
      angular.forEach(response, function(item) {
        //in my response I have the correct values
        values.push({'label:' : item.label, 'value:' : item.value});
      });

      $scope.data = values;
    });
  }
```

On the view I have this

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <nvd3 options="options"
              data="data"
              config="config"
              events="events"
              api="api"></nvd3>

      </div>
```

But I always get this error when trying to render the graphic.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/nvd3/nv.d3.js:3684:78
    at Array.filter (native)
    at SVGSVGElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/nvd3/nv.d3.js:3684:42)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/d3/d3.js:8114:14
    at d3_selection_each (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/d3/d3.js:888:30)
    at Array.d3_transitionPrototype.each (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/d3/d3.js:8112:7)
    at Array.chart (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/nvd3/nv.d3.js:3664:15)
    at Array.d3_selectionPrototype.call (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/d3/d3.js:895:14)
    at Object.link.scope.api.updateWithData (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-nvd3/dist/angular-nvd3.min.js:1:5556)
    at Object.link.scope.api.updateWithOptions (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-nvd3/dist/angular-nvd3.min.js:1:4752)
  (anonymous function)  
  $get  
  $get.Scope.$digest    
  scopePrototype.$digest    
  $get.Scope.$apply 
  scopePrototype.$apply 
  done  
  completeRequest   
  requestLoaded
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Wath is the output of console.log(response)?

Comment: Then it should work fine .... can you debug (or do a console.log) and see what do you have in $scope.data and values arrays after the angular.forEach?

Comment: My data structure was incorrect, the arrays has to be named 'values'